# Declare + Instantiate a new Object of a Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

I am looking for the correct syntax to Declare and Instantiate a new Object of a class. I seem to achieve this in Console Applications but I can't seem to get this working in WinForms. In Console Apps I did this which worked:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student StudentClass = new Student();
```

In WinForms I have been tasked to Declare an Object at the form level and then instantiate it in the `Form_Load()` event handler so I came up with this but I can't get it working:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Book Book1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Book1 = new Book();
```

I get the error:

> The type or namespace name 'Book' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have a Book.cs Class in my Project

Comment: Is `Book` in the same namespace?

Comment: If the file is now in the same project as `Form1`, then most likely you copied the `Book.cs` file from the console application and it has a different namespace. So as the error message it telling you - **you are missing a using directive**. Either change the namespace of the `Book` class inside `Book.cs` to match your new assembly, or add a `using` directive at the top of the `Form1` file to make this namespace visible inside this scope. If the file is in a different project, then you also need to add a reference to that other assembly.

Comment: Thanks, I simply renamed the namespace and it's working fine now :)

Comment: Question answered, thread can be closed :)